# i want to make a time based transaction using solidity in smart contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, dapps

i am creating smart contract for lottery system and i am stuck on a problem, i want to make a time based transaction like a certain amount of players are added into the array then a time stamp should run and on specific time which i will declare should send the amount to the winner,
I tried a lot of things but couldn't find the answer please anyone can help here is my code

this is the part where i am stuck, i am trying to enter into the lottery from this this function and when conditions met i want to transfer the amount through the same function cause i want to automate the winner function ..........
i hope you got my point

```
function enter() public payable{
   require(msg.value > 1 wei);
   players.push(msg.sender);

 if(players.length==10){
     start = block.timestamp;
 }

 if(block.timestamp>= start+totalTime){
    uint index = random()% players.length;
    players[index].transfer(this.balance);
    dead[index].transfer((this.balance*2)/100);
    winner = players[index];
    players = new address[](0);
 }
```

this is my complete code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;

contract Lottery{
   address public manager;
   address[] public players;
   address [0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead] private dead;
   address public winner;
   uint start;
    uint end;
   uint totalTime=50;
  
   constructor()public {
      manager = msg.sender;
   }

   function enter() public payable{
      require(msg.value > 1 wei);
      players.push(msg.sender);
   
    if(players.length==10){
        start = block.timestamp;
    }

    if(block.timestamp>= start+totalTime){
       uint index = random()% players.length;
       players[index].transfer(this.balance);
       dead[index].transfer((this.balance*2)/100);
       winner = players[index];
       players = new address[](0);
    }
   }
   function random() private view returns (uint){
       return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty,now,players));
   }
   function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
       return address(this).balance;
   }
   function getPlayers() public view returns (address[]){
       return players;
   }
   function getWinner() public view returns (address){
       return winner;
   }
    function getTime() public view returns (uint){
       return end-block.timestamp;
   }
}
```

Comment: So you want the SmartContract to declare the winner on its own, after some time had elapsed?

Comment: Try to avoid using `block.timestamp` in a lottery contract. You're not the first one who comes up with this idea and there are a lot of projects that got hacked through this use of `block.timestamp`. First of all miners can exploit this by tweaking the timestamp (they can add or remove around 15 seconds from the actual time, and second `block.timestamp` is a value that can be predicted

Comment: Also this function `function random() private view returns (uint){
       return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty,now,players));
   }`is absolutely not random. You contract can be easily exploited by other contracts. A use can create a new contract, wait until 9 already joined the lottery, execute the pseudo-`random` function and depending on the value they get, they will join the lottery and win it.
Try finding another solution.

Comment: then what do you recommend rather than using block.timestamp

Comment: @MoeedElahi So what's the problem? the transaction reverts, run out of gas, does nothing, ... . Looking at it you send the whole balance with `players[index].transfer(this.balance)`, then tries to transfer `       dead[index].transfer((this.balance*2)/100)` again, it doesn't make much sense since balance will be zero at that point.

Comment: it's not a big issue I'll take care of the transaction problem but my main issue is in the nested condition the second condition is not running properly 1st) I want the timestamp to run on the first condition which is running properly and the second thing is the 2nd) I want the 2nd condition to run after the timestamp is completed but its not running that way i don't know that the problem is in 2nd conditio0n or the timestamp i have tried everything